# php ajax control session variables disappearing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a page where a user logs in and some session variables are set:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "Bob Smith";
$_SESSION['company'] = "acme Co";
$_SESSION['someData'] = "yes";
```

so far so good.

now the user is at landing.php and here i have a series of links on left side that users user for navigation.

```
<li class='menu' id='createUser'>Create New user</li>
<li class='menu' id='modUser'>Modify User</li>
<li class='menu' id='reports'>Reports</li>
<li class='menu' id='api'>API Management</li>
<li class='menu' id='logout'>Logout</li>
```

and the jquery for navigation:

```
$('.menu,.menu2').click(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: "admin.php",
        data: "action="+action,
        success: function(result){
            $('#modData').html(result);
     }
});
```

admin.php returns an include of the var action's php page.  so modUser.php or reports.php and so on are returned with different forms and data on them.

now. The strange thing i cant figure out.  When i click on any link.  My session variables are still set.  When i click again on any link(except logout), All session variable data is gone.  I have no session_destroy anywhere except in logout.php

print_r($_SESSION) on any of those pages show variables the first time only....second click i get the result

```
 Array()
```

I have session_start() on every page possible.

I know this is a longshot, and you probably need a ton more info, but is there anything inherently wrong here that I am missing that causes session data to be removed.

admin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['action'] == "reports")
{
    include('reports.php');
}
if ($_POST['action'] == "logout");{
    include('logout.php');
}
if ($_POST['action'] == "api"){
    include('apiMgmt.php');
}
```

?>

Comment: check `session_id()` on each  of the pages. if the value's changing, then you're losing your session cookies and getting new/empty sessions. Not likely the sessions are being DESTROYED, just getting abandoned. Usually that's a cookie settings problem.

Comment: domain stays the same throughout? tried at least two browsers

Comment: seems like your issue is probably in admin.php somewhere.  maybe you should post that.

Comment: session id stays the same.  adding admin.php info to question now.

Comment: "When i click again on any link(except logout), All session variable data is gone." Did you write this correctly? It sounds like you've mixed up your logic in the logout bit... So it's logging out always instead of only on logout?

Comment: "I have session_start() on every page possible." ... except you don't have it on admin.php where the problem is.

Comment: I wrote this poorly.  Any link i click session data goes away.  it goes away correctly when i click logout.php

Comment: session_start is on there. I missed it in my c/p. sorry.

Comment: there could be 2 issues, you're not getting to the _SESSION register in your condition or session_start isn't on all the pages.

Comment: if session_start wasnt there, or session werent registering correctly, i shouldnt be able to see it the first click through....I do, its the second click i lose everything....

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems you might be facing is the include part of your admin.php.  While you want to have a session_start() almost always at the beginning of each new file, the include section is just appending the code to the landing php file, having multiple session starts in one 'large' file.

One way you could solve this is in each 'child' php file, have the session start written as -

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}
```

This is for PHP version 5.4 and later.  For earlier versions, use

```
if (session_id() == '') {
  session_start();
}
```

Comment: Well,  You're answer was not correct, but it did lead me to the solution, so u get bonus points.

Comment: added my own answer,  in admin.php the 2nd if statement if ($_POST['action'] == "logout");  has an erroneous semi-colon....so it was firing every time.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  if ($_POST['action'] == "reports")
  {
include('reports.php');
  }
  if ($_POST['action'] == "logout");{    <------
include('logout.php');
  }
  if ($_POST['action'] == "api"){
include('apiMgmt.php');
  }
```

remove the semi-colon in the logout if statement fixes the problem.